# how to send retrofit request body from postman when request body is just json

Tags: android, retrofit2, postman, okhttp

I'm send data to rest service using retrofit and it works but when server crash and i need to test the api in postman but when using postman data is null,i can see that data are delivered using dump and die but when trying to access it return null

```
    @POST("adToCart")
    Call<CartDataResponse> addToCart(@Body CartData cartData);
```

Comment: create json string of cartData and send from post man in form data with "cartData" as key and value is your object in string format. something like cartData:{"user_id":"334"} in body of request.

Comment: i don't want to made changes in back-end

Comment: there is no need of change in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your request body is `CartData`, you can just simply use `Gson.toJson(cartData)` where, if you're using google `Gson` libray with retrofit and `cartData` is an object of `CartData.java` or the request model `class`. Print that value of the `json` which you have got from `Gson.toJson(cartData)`, copy the `json` and put it into the `body` portion of postman and make sure that you have fill the `hearder` and correct endpoint, Then hit 'send' button which will give you your expected response. If not please share your steps for confirmation.

Comment: Share you `CartData` class and the request model as well

Comment: CartData code https://gist.github.com/IslamAssem/563abca49f8a8a8adbd168c1972a179e